# Local Storage no longer syncing for the same domain?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

One browser tab contains a top level window with Domain A with an embedded frame that comes from Domain B. There is also another tab that contains a page that only points to Domain B. Previously, Local Storage for Domain B in both tabs were in sync (the values were always the same), but now I notice that they are separate. Is it expected? If so, is there a way to handle this so that they are both in sync again? I'm on Chrome Version 118.0.5993.71 (Official Build) (64-bit)